# Saving symbolic Tensor for later use

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am following the tutorial from TensorFlow for a [chatbot](https://www.kaggle.com/code/yening2000/chatbot-nlp-1/notebook) and was wondering how you could save the output of the encoder later passes? I know the values of symbolic tensors can be printed out with tf.print and they can be written into tf.TensorArray's. Because of how the chatbot model is structured, global variables will not be affected by changes made to them during training, so how does one save these tensors in things like tf.TensorArray's for later iterations during training?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you compile your model with `run_eagerly=True` then you can properly use global variables during training. If you want to save symbolic tensors between batches, it gets a little more difficult so I opted to make my layers as classes that don't use symbolic tensors instead.